# Subset rows based on "start and stop" strings

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, rows

looking to write an R script that will search a column for a specific value and begin sub setting rows until a specific text value is reached.

Example:

```
    X1  X2 
[1,] "a" "1"
[2,] "b" "2"
[3,] "c" "3"
[4,] "d" "4"
[5,] "e" "5"
[6,] "f" "6"
[7,] "c" "7"
[8,] "k" "8"
```

What I'd like to do is search through `X1` until the letter `'c'` is found, and begin to subset rows until another letter `'c'` is found, at which point the subset procedure would stop. Using the above example, the result should be a vector containing `c(3,4,5,6,7)`.

Assume there will be no more than 2 rows where `X1` equals `'c'`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are three c's found? Also, please share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can copy/paste into R for testing.

Comment: Good point and something I forgot to mention - no character will ever be duplicated more than twice so there will be clear beginning and end points

Comment: `Reduce(seq, which(your_data[, 1] == 'c')[1:2])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lookup where a value is with the function `which`, and use that as in index to get the values you are looking for. If you want everything from the first to the second "c", it would look like this:

```
indices <- which(df$X1=='c')
range <- indices[1]:indices[2]
df$X2[range]
```